# Can I use StringReplace to write the number of row which I am replacing?

Tags: export, string-manipulation, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I have a text file which I have constructed as

```
savedXText = ExportString[savedX, "Text"]
savedXText2 = 
  StringReplace[
   savedXText, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", 
    "t" -> "m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi", "u" -> "m.phi[i]*180/np.pi"}];
Export["testStack.txt", savedXText2];
```

This will be used later on in a python program.

testStack.txt has three rows (however, in the future it could have more or less depending on the number of nodes I am working with). Unfortunately, the code doesn't do what I need.

I would like to know if there is a way to aknowledge the row in which one is by writing it in lammda and phi. i.e for the first row I would like to know if

`"t" -> "m.lammda1[i]*180/np.pi"` and `"u" -> "m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi`

can be written and in a similar fashion,

`"t" -> "m.lammda2[i]*180/np.pi"` and `"u" -> "m.phi2[i]*180/np.pi`
for the second row and so on.

I am certain that it can be done by using a [for loop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) or a [table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) where a variable takes the value of the row of savedText (the original before the [StringReplace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html)) and then use [StringForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) or [toString](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) in the StringReplace, but I cannot do it.

This is the first row of testStack.txt

```
-19.995904426195736*Sinc(0.04188790204786391*(0. + m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi))*Sinc(0.08975979010256552*(-65. + m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi)) - 37.58848602557134*Sinc(0.04188790204786391*(75. + m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi))*Sinc(0.08975979010256552*(-65. + m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi)) - 26.820905985723094*Sinc(0.04188790204786391*(0. + m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi))*Sinc(0.08975979010256552*(-30. + m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi)) - 15.904862946583352*Sinc(0.04188790204786391*(75. + m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi))*Sinc(0.08975979010256552*(-30. + m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi))
```

Comment: Have you looked at MapIndexed?  If the rows are split into a list, then MapIndexed may be used to get the row number (the index) and perhaps this will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do it:

```
editLine = "a * Sinc[ b*t + c*u ]";
noEdit = "# COMMENT";

text = {noEdit, noEdit, editLine, editLine, noEdit, editLine};

count = 0;
newText = StringReplace[text, {
    "[" -> "(", "]" -> ")",
    "t" :> ("m.lammda" <> ToString[++count] <> "[i]*180/np.pi"),
    "u" :> ("m.phi" <> ToString[count] <> "[i]*180/np.pi")}];

newText // ColumnForm


(* 

# COMMENT
# COMMENT
a * Sinc( b*m.lammda1[i]*180/np.pi + c*m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi )
a * Sinc( b*m.lammda2[i]*180/np.pi + c*m.phi2[i]*180/np.pi )
# COMMENT
a * Sinc( b*m.lammda3[i]*180/np.pi + c*m.phi3[i]*180/np.pi )

*)
```